# Повторение значений v-model в двойном цикле

Tags: vue.js

Цель создать форму,**Главная** котороя динамичная (добавить/удалить). Она имеет 3 поля И **Внутр.**следующий цикл в котором есть динамическая часть добавления/удаления контактов.
**Главная** отрабативает норм, а вот **внутр** повторяет себя из пред.**Главная** .

Визуальный вид:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
TQ1 Не повторяет, так как масив уже существует с пустыми значениями.
TQ2 и TQ2 **Главная** имена не менаются, все норм. А вот **Внутр.** вери бед .

**КОД**

template

```
<div v-for="(form, index) in PeopleformsData" :key="index" class="next_table">
            <div class="item_data_people">
                <div class="pib_people">
                    <div class="item_peole">
                        <label for="first_name">Прізвище</label>
                        
                        <b-input
                            id="first_name"
                            :name="`first_name-${index}`"
                            placeholder="Прізвище"
                            v-model="form.first_name"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_bad_peole">
                        <label for="namePeople">Ім’я</label>
                        <b-input
                            id="namePeople"
                            :name="`namePeople-${index}`"
                            placeholder="Ім’я"
                            v-model="form.namePeople"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="item_bad_peole">
                        <label for="last_name">По-батькові</label>
                        <b-input
                            id="last_name"
                            :name="`last_name-${index}`"
                            placeholder="По-батькові"
                            v-model="form.last_name"   
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- second while -->
                <div class="data_offender" :name="`data_offender-${inx}-${index}`"  v-for="(contact, inx) in form.contact_offender" :key="inx">
                    <div class="type_data">
                        <label for="payment-type-input">Тип даних</label>
                        <b-select
                            id="payment-type-input"
                            class="pay_cards"
                            :name="`choice_form_contacts-${inx}`"
                            v-model="contact.offender_type"
                            :options="offender_types"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="output_data" v-if="contact.offender_type===1">
                        <label for="bank-card-input-fraud">Телефон *</label>
                        <b-input
                            
                            :name="`phone_data-${inx}`"
                            v-model="contact.phone_data"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="output_data" v-if="contact.offender_type===2">
                        <label for="bank-card-input-fraud">Електронна пошта *</label>
                        <b-input
                            :name="`email_data-${inx}`"
                            v-model="contact.email_data"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="output_data" v-if="contact.offender_type===3">
                        <label for="bank-card-input-fraud">Instagram-аккаунт *</label>
                        <b-input
                            :name="`instagram_data-${inx}`"
                            v-model="contact.instagram_data"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="output_data" v-if="contact.offender_type===4">
                        <label for="bank-card-input-fraud">Нікнейм Telegram *</label>
                        <b-input
                            :name="`telegram_data-${inx}`"
                            v-model="contact.telegram_data"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="output_data" v-if="contact.offender_type===5">
                        <label for="bank-card-input-fraud">Facebook-аккаунт *</label>
                        <b-input
                            :name="`facebook_data-${inx}`"
                            v-model="contact.facebook_data"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="output_data" v-if="contact.offender_type===6">
                        <label for="bank-card-input-fraud">IР-адреса *</label>
                        <b-input
                            :name="`ip_data-${inx}`"
                            v-model="contact.ip_data"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="output_data" v-if="contact.offender_type===7">
                        <label for="bank-card-input-fraud">Інше *</label>
                        <b-input
                            :name="`other_data-${inx}`"
                            v-model="contact.other_data"
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div class="button_add_type">
                        <button class="add_new_add_type" @click="addFormContact(index,inx)"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                        <button class="delete_add_type" @click="removeFormContact(index,inx)" :disabled="!delete_active"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
                    </div> 
                </div>

                
            </div>
            <div class="button_data_people">
                <button class="add_new_data_pay" @click="addFormPeople"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button>
                <button class="delete_data_pay" @click="removeFormPeople(index)"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
            </div>
                
            
        </div>
```

script

```
export default {
data() {
return {
PeopleformsData:[
            {
                first_name: '',
                namePeople:'',
                last_name:'',
                contact_offender:[
                    {
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
    methods: {
        addFormPeople() {
            this.PeopleformsData.push(Object.assign({}, defaultFormVModelsPeople));
            console.log('***PEOPLE***',this.PeopleformsData)
            
        },
        removeFormPeople(i) {
            Vue.delete(this.PeopleformsData, i)
            console.log('***PEOPLE***',this.PeopleformsData)
        },
        addFormContact(i) {
            this.PeopleformsData[i].contact_offender.push(Object.assign({}, 
            this.PeopleformsData.contact_offender))
            console.log('***CONTACT***___ADD',this.PeopleformsData)
            
        },
        removeFormContact(i,inx) {
            Vue.delete(this.PeopleformsData[i].contact_offender, inx)
            console.log('***CONTACT***___DELETE',this.PeopleformsData)
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь :

```
addFormContact(i) {
        this.PeopleformsData[i].contact_offender.push(Object.assign({}, 
        this.PeopleformsData.contact_offender))
        console.log('***CONTACT***___ADD',this.PeopleformsData)
        
    },
```

Нужно передать совершенно новый {} с полями

в data :

```
PeopleM:{
            first_name: '',
            namePeople:'',
            last_name:'',
            contact_offender:[
                {
                },
            ],
            
        },
        ContactO:{
            offender_type:'',
            phone_data:'',
            email_data:'',
            instagram_data:'',
            telegram_data:'',
            facebook_data:'',
            ip_data:'',
            other_data:''
        }
```

Конечный результат :

```
addFormPeople() {
            let p = this.PeopleM
            p.contact_offender = []
            p.contact_offender.push(Object.assign({},this.ContactO))
            this.PeopleformsData.push(Object.assign({}, p ));
            console.log('***PEOPLE***',this.PeopleformsData)
            
        },
```